# JavaScript sort of Array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of arrays. I want it to be sorted by arrays' length.
I use `array.sort( (a, b) => a.length > b.length) );`

```
[ 
  [],
  [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 3, 3, 3, 3 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [],
  [ 5, 5 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ],
  [],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 5 ],
  [],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [],
  [ 3 ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 4 ],
  [],
  [ 5, 5, 5, 5 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 3, 3, 3 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [],
  [ 4, 4 ],
  [ 2, 2, 2 ],
  [],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 5 ] ]
```

But after all sorting returns this. Why array of length of 6 with 4 inside it is placed in the wrong place?

```
[ 
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 5 ],
  [],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 5, 5 ],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [ 4, 4 ],
  [ 3, 3 ],
  [ 3, 3 ],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2, 2 ],
  [ 3, 3, 3 ],
  [ 5, 5, 5, 5 ],
  [ 3, 3, 3, 3 ],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 4 ],
  [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ] ]
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Try `a.length - b.length` inside the sort function.

Comment: MDN explains the return value of the comparator function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control#Description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the sort function, you have to provide the max, min equal (+1 (>0 actually), -1 (<0 actually), 0 (for equals)), the faster way is by substract the results:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
  // ASC  -> a.length - b.length
  // DESC -> b.length - a.length
  return a.length - b.length ;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the sort function using the subtraction between lengths:

```js
  var a = [ 
  [],
  [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 3, 3, 3, 3 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [],
  [ 5, 5 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ],
  [],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 5 ],
  [],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [],
  [ 3 ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 4 ],
  [],
  [ 5, 5, 5, 5 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 5 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 3, 3, 3 ],
  [],
  [],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [],
  [ 4, 4 ],
  [ 2, 2, 2 ],
  [],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 5 ] ];
  a.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.length - b.length;
  });
  console.log(a);
```

Comment: That's actually the same you posted so great job to you too :)